# how to shift single value of a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using pandas `first_valid_index()` to get index of first non-null value of a column, how can I shifta single value of column rather than the whole column. i.e.

```
data = {'year': [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016,2017, 2018, 2019],
        'columnA': [10, 21, 20, 10, 39, 30, 31,45, 23, 56],
        'columnB': [None, None, None, 10, 39, 30, 31,45, 23, 56],
         'total': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700,800, 900, 1000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index('year')
print df
      columnA  columnB  total
year                         
2010       10      NaN    100
2011       21      NaN    200
2012       20      NaN    300
2013       10       10    400
2014       39       39    500
2015       30       30    600
2016       31       31    700
2017       45       45    800
2018       23       23    900
2019       56       56   1000

for col in df.columns:
    if col not in ['total']:
        idx = df[col].first_valid_index()
        df.loc[idx, col] = df.loc[idx, col] + df.loc[idx, 'total'].shift(1)

print df     

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift'
```

desired result:

```
print df
      columnA  columnB  total
year                         
2010       10      NaN    100
2011       21      NaN    200
2012       20      NaN    300
2013       10      310    400
2014       39       39    500
2015       30       30    600
2016       31       31    700
2017       45       45    800
2018       23       23    900
2019       56       56   1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter all column names, where is least one `NaN` value and then use [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) with column `total`:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col not in pd.Index(['total']).union(df.columns[~df.isnull().any()]):
        idx = df[col].first_valid_index()
        df.loc[idx, col] += df.total.shift().loc[idx]
print (df)
      columnA  columnB  total
year                         
2010       10      NaN    100
2011       21      NaN    200
2012       20      NaN    300
2013       10    310.0    400
2014       39     39.0    500
2015       30     30.0    600
2016       31     31.0    700
2017       45     45.0    800
2018       23     23.0    900
2019       56     56.0   1000
```

Comment: Is column `Total` always last?

Comment: Or better, is possible if in column `Total` are `NaN` values?

Answer (score 2):

is that what you want?

```
In [63]: idx = df.columnB.first_valid_index()

In [64]: df.loc[idx, 'columnB'] += df.total.shift().loc[idx]

In [65]: df
Out[65]:
      columnA  columnB  total
year
2010       10      NaN    100
2011       21      NaN    200
2012       20      NaN    300
2013       10    310.0    400
2014       39     39.0    500
2015       30     30.0    600
2016       31     31.0    700
2017       45     45.0    800
2018       23     23.0    900
2019       56     56.0   1000
```

---

**UPDATE:** starting from Pandas 0.20.1 [the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix).

Comment: `for col in df.columns:
    if col not in ['total']:
        idx = df[col].first_valid_index()
        print df.ix[idx, col] + df.total.shift().ix[idx] '

Comment: @ArchieTiger, why are you using the for loop?